# Texture rendering and VBO's [OpenGL/SDL/C++]

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glsl

So, I've been working on a little game project for a bit and I've hit a snag that's annoying me to no end. I load an obj file which then gets rendered after being put into a VBO. This part works fine, no problemo. However, I've been trying to get it to render the accompanying texture with the supplied UVs with no success. Currently, I just get a matte green colouration on my model. Upon investigating it in GDE, I've seen that texture gets loaded fine and occupies the GL_TEXTURE0 unit, so that's not the issue. I believe it may be my binding but I have no idea why this would fail...

```
void Model_Man::render_models()
{
    for(int x=0; x<models.size(); x++)
    {
        if(models.at(x).visible==true)
        {
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,models.at(x).t_buff);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,models.at(x).i_buff);

            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,0,0);

            glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

            glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,&models.at(x).uvs[0]);
            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            int tex_loc = glGetUniformLocation(models.at(x).shaderid,"color_texture");
            glUniform1i(tex_loc,GL_TEXTURE0);
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, models.at(x).mats.at(0).texid);

            c_render.use_program(models.at(x).shaderid);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,models.at(x).f_index.size()*3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
            c_render.use_program();
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
    }
}
```

And my shader files...

Shader.frag

```
uniform sampler2D color_texture;
void main() {
    // Set the output color of our current pixel
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(color_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

Shader.vert

```
void main() {           
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

    // Set the position of the current vertex 
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

And yes, I know I'm currently being horribly inefficient with my render loop :P but I'm already planning on refactoring it, I am just attempting to get this single model to draw correctly with everything I'm aiming to do. I have no clue why it wouldn't be rendering with the texture correctly applied - unless it's because I need to interleave my arrays but I'm still supplying it with uv data so I don't see why it fails.

Comment: Can you render it fine without your shader?  Also, I don't suppose you're using a non power-of-two texture on hardware that doesn't support it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call that set the sampler uniform shall not set GL_TEXTUE0, but actually 0.

Indeed:

```
glUniform1i(location, 0)
```

---

For setting up a sampler uniform do:

```
glUseProgram(progId);
// ...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texUnit);
glBindTexture(texId);
glUniform1i(texUnit);
```

The main concept is that the uniform variable are a shader program state (it is mantained until you re-link the program or reset the uniform value). Without binding a program, glUniform1i shall fail since there's not shader program at which it can set the uniform value!

---

As a general advice, call *glGetError* after each OpenGL call to detect these conditions. Most of those calls can be removed by preprocessor in release version.

Comment: Ah! Silly mistake I guess :P Unfortunately, my texture is still not being applied properly :( If any additional code would be helpful I can gladly supply it, I just didn't want to make the initial post a giant wall of text.

Comment: You also don't bind the texture before calling glActiveTexture. Instead you did after.

Comment: Tried it, still no luck. :/ Is it perhaps because I'm not interleaving the UV data in the vertex array? This was my original hypothesis, but my attempts to interleave the data originally left everything a mess so I attempted to simplify things until it worked.

Comment: See edits: you don't bind the program before setting the uniform.

Comment: Ah, whoops. In the midst of swapping everything around in a blind hope of achieving something I never returned that to the way I had it. I'm still having no luck rendering it, however. GDE still gives me nothing useful other than reassuring me that my texture is loading properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, found out that the big issue was that while I was binding a texture, I wasn't actually setting it in a way that it was understood as being used. Setting glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texUnit); in combination with glActiveTexture(); ended up being the final solution.